# Upload picture to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I've done a single upload for image and put image to canvas, here is the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wvnmxj0q/). Now, the problem is that when I upload a picture and then I want to upload another one the previous picture still remain underneath.

This is my code:

**JS:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('main');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInputTest');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', imageLoader, false);

function imageLoader() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {

            var MAX_WIDTH = 150;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 150;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        }
        img.src = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="fileInputTest" />
<canvas id="main" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main {
  border: 2px dotted black;
  border-radius: 5px position: absolute;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wvnmxj0q/)**

Comment: [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) your canvas... But I don't see why you even use a canvas here, and you absolutely don't need a FileReader neither...

Comment: I'm using it for customizing a t-shirt. When I upload the picture to canvas it should appear on the center of the t-shirt. It's not working with clearRect...

Comment: It does work https://jsfiddle.net/wvnmxj0q/1/ and since I'm in a good mood, here is without the unnecessary FileReader: https://jsfiddle.net/wvnmxj0q/2/

Comment: Oh, that's perfect. Thank you very much. Also, do you know how can I upload the picture to the center of the canvas?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wvnmxj0q/3/

Comment: You're the best. Cheers mate! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this before you draw your image in context.

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
```

You just have to clear your canvas area before drawing your image.